# How i can hide add to cart button for non logged in visitors? Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I need to hide the button (add to cart) if user user logged out.
How i can hide add to cart button for non logged in visitors? Prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0):

It just can be done using custom theme.

You have to add new condition before display "add to cart" button to check customer group.